# Adding a double spaced line after chapter heading

Tags: spacing, formatting, chapters

I'm working on formatting a thesis for graduate school, and they're asking me to put one double spaced line after the chapter heading. I'm using someone else's template, and trying to modify it as needed.

Here's my current code:

```
\documentclass[11pt,letterpaper,twoside]{report}

% Layout
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{setspace}

\usepackage{indentfirst}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat*{\section}{\normalsize\bfseries}
\titleformat*{\subsection}{\normalsize\bfseries}

\usepackage{sectsty} % Used to control chapter and section headings, 

\usepackage[subfigure]{tocloft}

% Citation style
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{apalike}

% include citations inline
\usepackage{bibentry}
\nobibliography*

% Figures
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{listings}

% Math
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

% Typography
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{enumitem}

% Macro support
\usepackage{xspace}

% PDF links
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref} % backref=page


\input{common/layout}

% Use proper margins.
\geometry{letterpaper,left=1in,top=1in,right=1in,bottom=1in,nohead}



% double-space text
\doublespacing

% Center chapter titles, omit page numbers.
\titleformat{\chapter}[block] 
{\normalfont\bfseries\centering\singlespacing}{}{0pt}{}


\titleformat*{\section}{\normalfont\bfseries}

%header sizes
\titleformat*{\section}{\bfseries}
\titleformat*{\subsection}{\bfseries}
\titleformat*{\subsubsection}{\bfseries}

% Extend to 2in top margins
% Leave 22pts = 2x font size after heading
\titlespacing{\chapter}{0in}{0.62in}{22pt}

% Indent paragraphs four spaces throughout the thesis/dissertation.
\setlength{\parindent}{4ex}

% Tweak spacing of paragraph labels.
\titlespacing{\paragraph}{0in}{0.08in}{0.07in}

% We want numbered subsubsections
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}

% We need to double-space between footnotes.
\setlength{\footnotesep}{11pt}

% We don't want crazy vertical spacing.
\raggedbottom

% We don't want abandoned words.
\clubpenalty=10000 
\widowpenalty=10000

% Prevent awkward hyphenations.
\hyphenation{Raj-kumar}

\begin{document}
\chapter{This chapter title should be 2 inches below the top of the page and have a double spaced line before the body}

There should be one double-spaced line between this one and the chapter heading.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Missing `\documentclass` in your MWE.

Comment: @Mico Per your last question, that's just the instructions I have from the graduate school. As for your others, are those germane to my specific question? If not, then I appreciate the comment, but I'd rather take an "if it ain't broke, don't fix it" approach. I've been going back and forth with my school enough.

Comment: @User23456234 Sorry, it was in there and didn't show up for some reason. Writing it again seems to make it work now.

Comment: @Mico I appreciate the comments! It's just that this isn't a template I plan to use again, and I've got a more immediate issue as well with the spacing. If I wasn't up against a deadline, I'd be a lot more willing to experiment with that kind of thing, but I'm already not very comfortable with this stuff, so I'm worried about changing a package and messing something up on accident. I'm sorry if I came off as rude or unappreciative.